# Gridview and asp.net dropdownlist, adding select all

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I currently have a dropdownlist which is filled from a SQLDatasource from SQL Server table called "Users"

```
select s.id, s.Forename + ' ' + s.Surname as Name from User s
where s.Active = '1'
Order by Name
```

I then have a gridview which is displaying the results based on the id of the selected user from the dropdownlist

I would like to add a "Select all users" option in the dropdown menu so that all users are retrieved and displayed in the gridview

Gridview SQL

```
select sup.id, p.plan_name, sup.document_name, sup.Expiry_Date from 
User_Plan sup
join Plan_Type p on p.id = sup.Plan_Type_ID

where sup.User_ID = @sid and sup.Active = '1' and sup.Expiry_Date >= GETDATE()
```

What would be the best approach here?

Can you add something the dropdownlist so that @sid would bring back all results?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like This

Insert a `--Select All Users--` in the Dropdown with a 0 Index (Sid) and

```
DropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("--Select All Users--"));
```

The SQL Query is

```
select sup.id, p.plan_name, sup.document_name, sup.Expiry_Date from 
User_Plan sup
join Plan_Type p on p.id = sup.Plan_Type_ID

where sup.User_ID = Case When @sid=0 Then sup.User_ID else @sid end 
and sup.Active = '1' and sup.Expiry_Date >= GETDATE()
```

I am assuming that the `DataValuefield` of the Dropdown is User_Id and is been Passed in the SQL Query the above will select all the Users if the `@sid` is 0 or the User only based on the `@sid` value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yourDropDown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select ALl", "2"));
```

Here 2 is value of the item so you can give any value you want that will bring all records from database.